# ASP.NET MVC & Entity Framework stored procedures

Tags: asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, ef-database-first

My ASP.NET MVC web app needs to get data from existing database using T-SQL stored procedures. I've seen tutorials on how to do that using the code-first approach (basically for a model named `Product`, the Entity Framework generates stored procedures like `Product_Update`, `Product_Delete`, etc).

But in my case I can't use code-first b/c the database and the stored procedures already exist and their names don't follow this convention. What's the way to go? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

- Begin Edited 2017-03-28

If I go about using straight ADO.NET classes as Shyju and WillHua said, will data annotations on my Model data classes work? If not, how else can validation, etc be implemented?

If I follow this approach, do I need to reference Entity Framework in my project at all?

- End Edited 2017-03-28

Comment: You can always use old school ado.net (SqlCommand) ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Entity Framework you could do something similar to the following:

```
        var startDateParam = new SqlParameter("StartDate", 8) { Value = startDate };
        var endDateParam = new SqlParameter("EndDate", 8) { Value = endDate };
        var parameters = new[] { startDateParam, endDateParam };

        var result= Context.Database.SqlQuery<CampaignReferralReportItem>("CampaignReferralReportItems @StartDate, @EndDate", parameters).ToList<CampaignReferralReportItem>();
        return result;
```

So what you've got here is the declaration of two parameters which are passed into the Stored Procedure 'CampaignReferralReportItems'. After the query is complete, the result is mapped as closely as possible to the class CampaignReferralReportItem.

Keep in mind the order of the properties must be identical as the query results or the mapping can throw exceptions.

It's worth noting that the Context stated in the above code is your DataContext.

Also, before you start throwing this kind of code everywhere. It might be worthwhile looking at the [Repository pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest either using [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper), which I am strating to use, and love for it's speed - or, [Entity Framework, and 'Update model from Database' - so, a database first approach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/setting-up-database), where the references to the procs are pulled in.

But, I'd suggest Dapper, as it's pretty simple and quick.